# Are utf-8 std::locales missing on iOS?

Tags: c++, ios, locale

I'm trying to get `std::locale` that will be able to handle Russian symbols in my code.

```
std::optional< std::locale > TryGetLocale( const std::string& name )
{
      try
      {
         std::locale res( name );
         if( std::isalpha( L'ф', res ) )
            return res;
         else
             return std::nullopt;
      }
      catch( ... )
      {
         return std::nullopt;
      }
   }

   std::optional< std::locale > TryGenerateLocale( const std::string& name, const std::string base_name )
   {
      try
      {
         boost::locale::generator gen;
         std::locale base( base_name );
         auto res = std::locale( gen.generate( base, name ) );
         if( std::isalpha( L'ф', res ) )
            return res;
         else
             return std::nullopt;
      }
      catch( ... )
      {
         return std::nullopt;
      }
   }

   std::locale TryGetLocale()
   {
      auto res = TryGetLocale( "ru_RU.utf8" );
      if( !res )
         res = TryGetLocale( "ru_RU.UTF-8" );
      if( !res )
         res = TryGenerateLocale( "ru_RU.UTF-8", "en_US.UTF-8" );
      if( !res )
         res = TryGenerateLocale( "ru_RU.UTF-8", "en_US.utf8" );
      if( !res )
      {
         using namespace U_ICU_NAMESPACE;
         int32_t count;
         const Locale* list = Locale::getAvailableLocales( count );
         for( size_t i = 0; i < static_cast< size_t >( count ); ++i )
         {
            res = TryGenerateLocale( "ru_RU.UTF-8", std::string( list[ i ].getName() ) + ".utf8" );
            if( res )
               break;
            res = TryGenerateLocale( "ru_RU.UTF-8", std::string( list[ i ].getName() ) + ".UTF-8" );
            if( res )
               break;
         }
      }
      if( !res )
      {
         std::terminate();
      }
      return *res;
   }
```

On Android and desktops everything is ok. On iOS simulator everything is also ok, but when I try to launch this code on iOS device - I'm getting terminate, because I can't get any named std::locale. Is it normal behavior for iOS devices? Do they miss any UTF-8 c++ locales?

Comment: Nope. In that question there is problem to identify system locale name, I have a problem, that I can't get any std::locale object other than one for C locale

Comment: When you get the available locales, can you print them out (or examine them in the debugger) and check which ones are available?

Comment: They could be using utf16.

Comment: As I know, there is no UTF-16 or UTF-32 locales at all.